# How to set limit th:each loop in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, loops, each, thymeleaf

How do I set a limit for an `each` loop in my `thymeleaf` HTML page?

For example:

```
<select id="places" onchange="onPlaceChange();">
    <option value="0">Select Place</option>
    <option th:each="p:${places}" th:text="${p.place_Name}" th:value="${p.id}"></option>
</select>
```

This code loops through items from a database and limit is the length of the list.

Here the list length is 14 and I want to set that limit to 7, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key would be to use the iteration status mechanism along with the `th:if` or `th:unless` conditional attributes.

Relevant references are at:

- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status
- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless

So in your case, it would look something along the lines of:

```
<option th:each="p,pStat : ${places}" th:text="${p.place_Name}" th:value="${p.id}" th:unless="${pStat.index > 7}"></option>
```

Edit:  This answer was written for Thymeleaf 2.1 (at the time), but should work with 3.0 in the same or similar manner. See: 
 https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: What should I do to loop the remaining 7 items to the end of that list in a seperate th:each?

Comment: @moonwalker:  You can loop through the remaining 7 items in a different <option th:each ...>.  Depending on the rest of your code, you might be able to do everything in one loop if you use a "Synthetic th:block tag" (search for that topic in the linked docs).